# How to get and initialize field through reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class `ColorConstants` with some static fields:

```
public class ColorConstants {
    public static final Color BLACK;
    public static final Color BLUE;
    public static final Color GREEN;
    public static final Color RED;
    // ....
}
```

I want to check if a given color (`String`) exists in that class.

Is using reflections the appropriate way?

```
String s = "RED";
Field f = ColorConstants.class.getField(s);
Color colorConstant = (Color) myField.get(null);
```

Here I'm not sure how to get the actual value.
So what I basically need is: either `ColorConstant.RED` (if exists) or `null` (if doesn't exist).

PS: `ColorConstants` is not my own class, I just work with it. So I can't change its structure to an enum.

Comment: I believe you will have compilation error there as you need to initialize final variables. Anyway Field f = ColorConstants.class.getField(s); should be sufficient. It will throw an exception if there is no such field. Consider using enum

Comment: `Enum` is definitely an easier way to go for this check (although conceptually I always find `enum`s hard when you're not really _enumerating_ all the possible outcomes...  Just providing examples).  If you're doing this a lot, you could add them to a `Map<String, Color>` when you initialise them and just check that instead though.

Comment: ColorConstants is not my own class, I just work with it. So I can't change its structure to an enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get the `Field` object by name as you already did, next you can test field existance by catching `NoSuchFieldException`:

```
Color colorConstant = null;
String s = "RED";
try {
  Field f = ColorConstants.class.getField(s);
  colorConstant = f.get(null);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e){
  // Nothing to do here colorConstant already null
}
return colorConstant;
```